# cant get bootstrap menu to appear inside tab slide out div

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Have been using this tab slideout plugin: http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html

Im trying to get a bootstrap nested menu to appear in the tab that slides out, but for some reason the menu appears below the div.

See the following  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2741/)

I think it would be really cool to have the menu slide out and fill the div of the slideout menu. Can anyone help improve the way it looks?

Answer (score 0):

Ok  i was able to make it fit into the div by changing dropdown-menu to dropdown here

http://jsfiddle.net/VFJbH/

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Not quite what I wanted...I want it to keep the style of the twitter bootstrap dropdown menu - see http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html. I imagine its the css of either bootstrap or the slideout plugin that is causing it to appear below.